# Fix "No primary or single unique constructor found for interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse" in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets

I want to build a Register and login module for my application and ran into the error in the title.

My login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Login</h1>
<form th:action="@{/login}" th:object="${login}" method="post">
  Username: <input type="text" th:field="*{username}"><br/>
  <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}" th:errors="*{username}"></p>
  Password: <input type="password" th:field="*{password}"><br/>
  <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}"></p>
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

My User Class:

```
package com.webprojekt.webblog.DAO;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.List;


@Data
@Entity(name = "user")
@Table
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "user_sequence",
            sequenceName = "user_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "user_sequence"
    )
    @Column(
            nullable = false
    )
    private long id;
    @Column(
            name = "name",
            nullable = true,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"

    )
    private String name;
    @Column(
            name = "is_user_admin"

    )
    boolean isAdmin;
    @Column(
            name = "username"
    )
    @NotEmpty
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$", message = "Only letters, digits and underscores allowed")
    private String username;
    @Column(
       name ="password"
    )
    @Size(min = 5, message = "your password must have at least 5 characters")
    private String password;
    @Transient
    private String password2;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Entry> entry;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Comment> comment;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.isAdmin=false;
    }
//DTO Login
    public User(String username, String password1) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password1;
    }
//DTO registration

    public User( String username, String password1, String password2) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password1;
        this.password2 = password2;
    }

    public User(String name, String username, String password, String password2) {
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.password2 = password2;
    }
}
```

My Session Class:

```
package com.webprojekt.webblog.DAO;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.UUID;

@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table
@Data
@Entity
public class Session {

    @Id
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    private Instant expiresAt;

    public Session(User user, Instant expiresAt) {
        this.user = user;
        this.expiresAt = expiresAt;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setExpiresAt(Instant expiresAt) {
        this.expiresAt = expiresAt;
    }
}
```

And SessionController:

```
package com.webprojekt.webblog.API;

import com.webprojekt.webblog.BussinesLayer.WebBlogServices;
import com.webprojekt.webblog.DAO.Session;
import com.webprojekt.webblog.DAO.User;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CookieValue;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Optional;
@Controller
public class SessionController {
   private WebBlogServices webBlogServices;

    @Autowired
    public SessionController(WebBlogServices webBlogServices) {
        this.webBlogServices = webBlogServices;
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("login", new User ("", ""));
        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String login(@ModelAttribute("login") User user, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Optional<User> optionalUser = webBlogServices.findByUsernameAndPassword(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword ());

        if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
            Session session = new Session(optionalUser.get(), Instant.now().plusSeconds(7*24*60*60)); //expires one week from now
            webBlogServices.addSession(session);

           //store the session ID in a cookie to keep the username secret
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie("sessionId", session.getId());
            response.addCookie(cookie);

            // Login successful
            return "redirect:/";
        }

        bindingResult.addError(new FieldError ("login", "password", "Login not successful."));

        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/logout")
    public String logout(@CookieValue(value = "sessionId", defaultValue = "") String sessionId, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Optional<Session> optionalSession = webBlogServices.findByIdAndExpiresAtAfter(sessionId, Instant.now());
        optionalSession.ifPresent(session -> webBlogServices.delete(session));

        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("sessionId", "");
        cookie.setMaxAge(0);
        response.addCookie(cookie);

        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

Console Log:

```
2023-02-26T18:44:00.439+01:00 ERROR 10952 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single unique constructor found for interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single unique constructor found for interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.getResolvableConstructor(BeanUtils.java:266) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:219) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:147) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:181) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:148) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
```

So far ive probably tried all solutions found through google, but didnt get a solution. Its my first time using technologies like Lombok, and HttpServletResponse. I know that i cannot instanciate an interface in java, but i dont know how to solve it anyways. Thank you guys in advance.

edit1:
My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.0.2
 

com.thalia
library
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
library
library

<java.version>17</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-jdbc

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Please add your pom file to the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Spring Boot 3 (and Spring Framework 6) require a baseline of Jakarte EE 10. You cannot use it with Java EE or Jakarte EE versions below that.

You have to remove the explicit dependency on `jakarta.servlet-api` from your `pom.xml`. Java Servlet 4 is below the baseline and in particular still uses the package names starting with `javax.servlet`.

If you remove the explicit dependency, Spring will pull in transitively the correct one. You then need to replace all imports starting with `javax.servlet` with `javax` replaced by `jakarta`, e.g.

```
import jakarta.servlet.http.Cookie;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
```

Comment: That's great to hear. If it worked for you, please accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know how to mark an answer as proper, but figured out :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace all imports starting with javax.servlet with javax replaced by jakarta,
e.g.

```
import jakarta.servlet.http.Cookie;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
```

Comment: your answer is no different than [the one above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75575636/13927534). Please avoid writing duplicate answers if you don't have anything new to add.

Answer (score 0):

you'd better to use jakarta package replace all of javax.servlet

I think so

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).